# Windows 10 HID descriptor error

Tags: windows, usb, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, usb-descriptor

Hello I am developing an embedded HID device which gives me an error when connected:

This device cannot start. (Code 10)

Extra end collection found or end collection not found.

This seems to be a problem with my Report Map, but according to HID tool it is fine:

```
char ReportDescriptor[52] = {
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
    0x85, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_ID (1)
    0x05, 0x09,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x03,                    //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x03,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x05,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x81, 0x03,                    //     INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
    0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
```

};

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using sizeof ReportDescriptor which is 52, but it has 50 bytes initialized?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have omitted a PHYSICAL COLLECTION item (which accounts for the extra END COLLECTION item at the end I guess). Did you mean:

```
char ReportDescriptor[52] = {
    0x05, 0x01,                    // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,                    // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x09, 0x01,                    //   USAGE (Pointer)
    0xA1, 0x00,                    //   COLLECTION (Physical) <-- inserted
    0x85, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_ID (1)
    0x05, 0x09,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_MINIMUM (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x03,                    //     USAGE_MAXIMUM (Button 3)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x03,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0x95, 0x01,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x05,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x81, 0x03,                    //     INPUT (Cnst,Var,Abs)
    0x05, 0x01,                    //     USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,                    //     USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                    //     USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81,                    //     LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7f,                    //     LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //     REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,                    //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06,                    //     INPUT (Data,Var,Rel)
    0xc0,                          //   END_COLLECTION
    0xc0                           // END_COLLECTION
};
```

The free [HID Report Descriptor Decoder tool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/) when invoked with:

```
rexx rd.rex -d samples/win10.rd
```

decodes this as:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 02        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010002 Mouse (CA=Application Collection) 
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x00010002: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Mouse, Type=CA)
09 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010001 Pointer (CP=Physical Collection) 
A1 00          (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00 Physical (Usage=0x00010001: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Pointer, Type=CP)
85 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1) 
05 09            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0009 Button Page 
19 01            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00090001 Button 1 Primary/trigger (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
29 03            (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00090003 Button 3 Tertiary (MULTI=Selector, On/Off, Momentary, or One Shot) 
15 00            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0 <-- Info: Consider replacing 15 00 with 14
25 01            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
95 03            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x03 (3) Number of fields  
75 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
81 02            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (3 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 01            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
75 05            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x05 (5) Number of bits per field  
81 03            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000003 (1 field x 5 bits) 1=Constant 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
05 01            (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 30            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010030 X (DV=Dynamic Value) 
09 31            (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010031 Y (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 81            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x81 (-127)  
25 7F            (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x7F (127)  
75 08            (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
95 02            (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x02 (2) Number of fields  
81 06            (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000006 (2 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 1=Variable 1=Relative 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
C0             (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Physical
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
*/
```

And:

```
rexx rd.rex -s samples/win10.rd
```

...generates a C typedef for it as follows:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: Mouse Pointer
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerButton1 : 1;              // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerButton2 : 1;              // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_MousePointerButton3 : 1;              // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 5;                                      // Pad
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerX;                         // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -127 to 127
  int8_t   GD_MousePointerY;                         // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -127 to 127
} inputReport01_t;
```